# Nginx set_proxy_header host adds www to the host

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host sub.domain.host.com;
    proxy_pass https://other.host.com/;
}
```

The host header ends up being **www**.sub.domain.host.com, is there a way to prevent the **www** from being added?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, I was wrong. You can create more levels on your domain.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77534/subdomain-of-subdomain-how-is-it-possible

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant, but the articles you link disagree with what you posted, you can look under the heading [second-level and lower level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Second-level_and_lower_level_domains)

Comment: Ops, found some more. Updated answer